Flutter:gradle build failed with error "A problem occurred evaluating root project
My Project runs fine then suddenly after i edit some image and run it, it gets error.
Here is the error I get when running flutter on my mobile phone emulator
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\fahad\AndroidStudioProjects\users\android\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > 'com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I seem to keep running into other issues related to this being caused by the gradle version or maybe google services version. I've tried several different versions. Currently using
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.1'
Build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}```



i tried to change the version of my gradle file but doesn't work and also i try to flutter clean and run.


Can you add your settings.gradle and also go to url and move to new Android implementation rather then using deprecated method.
